# Drupal template installation issue

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to install a drupal template but it shows me this error

```
  PHP memory limit  128M
    Consider increasing your PHP memory limit to 196M to help prevent errors in the installation process. Increase the memory limit by editing the memory_limit parameter in the file /opt/users/ipg/w/i/ipg.wintergtiranacom/php53/php.ini and then restart your web server (or contact your system administrator or hosting provider for assistance). See the Drupal requirements for more information.
```

I have tried the ini_set method the .htaccess method and I can't find the `/opt/users/ipg/w/i/ipg.wintergtiranacom/php53/php.ini`
path.
Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Go to you "php.ini" file as mention path /opt/users/ipg/w/i/ipg.wintergtiranacom/php53/php.ini  and search memory limit variable and increase the limit to 196M

Answer (score 0):

Try this

# mysql -u admin -p< Your Password>

mysql> set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

then exit and restart you WAMP.

and re-install the template.